# Image not being displayed properly

Tags: java, jsp, servlets

I am making a web application using jsp and servlets.In my web application I browse a image from browser and store it in a specified folder on my server side.But the problem is that ,that image is not being displayed in browser until i manually open that image once.

Once i open the image and then refresh my page,Then the image is displayed.What can be the reason for such thing?Please help

Comment: 'that image is not being displayed in browser'? What do you mean? Do you get a 404? What is 'manually open'??

Comment: @Ishtar No actually not 404.The image when opened by double clicking in the specified folder on server side then it opens smoothly,But when it is opened in browser for first time then it just shows blank space at that spot.

Comment: Does your image tag take the form `<img src='file.ext' />`? I've seen this happen when someone makes the mistake of doing like `<img src='file.ext'></img>`

Comment: @developerwjk No its of form <img src='file.ext' />

Comment: @user3522121 Have you checked whether the response have been loaded completely . And also ensure any content you are passing dynamically doesnt have errors mainly javascripts

Comment: @sankrish What you mean by checking weather  response have been loaded completely?

Answer (score 0):

Probable reason for this maybe your page doesn't read image at once and needs some time to read it..you can solve this problem by giving it a delay of some time..you can do this by

```
<%TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(5); %>
```

It will add a delay of `5 seconds`(you can change it accoriding to your needs) before the page loads..So your page will get sufficient time to read and form image on your page and you will not have to refresh the page again to display it..I was also facing same problem as yours and adding this statement solved it.